# Change to Art-Optimized Supersampling in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anti-aliasing

I was wondering if it's possible to change my viewing in Illustrator to art-optimized supersampling, instead of the type-optimized anti-aliasing that is default.

I'm not talking about the exporting of a file and changing the option there. I'm talking about viewing and working on artwork IN Illustrator. I know there is an option in Preferences > General to switch anti-aliasing on or off, but no option to change the type of anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

(No, there is no such option.)

Atleast as far as I can verify, the negative is very hard to prove. But this is hardly surprising as it would be much slower to work with.

---

### Update to this question (17.07.2016)

It seems that I am wrong, you can indeed do this with a bit of fiddling. While it is not global you can still do the same thing by placing all your data inside a master layer (you can have layers in layers) that applies this effect. To do this:

1. Select the layer that contains all your artwork (click circle next to layer name)
2. Apply a rasterize effect with the art optimized aa option and 72 dpi resolution (for pixel preview)

As a bonus you could super sample some shapes while keeping for example text text optimized.